# How can I fix or workaround this tableView textField autolayout glitch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I think the root cause is that the `estimatedRowHeight` is used to make assumptions about the underlying `UIScrollView.contentOffset`, but this will always be wrong by definition as it is a estimate. The real row heights are completely different depending on the cell content and device orientation.

Even if I implement `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` to provide closer estimates the glitches are still there.

So when you start at the top and scroll down all is well because the TableView learns the actual cell heights as it goes keeping the contentOffset in sync with the cell positions. But as soon as you rotate all the real cell heights change so the `UITableView` is now way out of sync, it doesn't know where to scroll to.

But there are even stranger things happening too, sometimes the `UITextField` cell will end up on top of another cell, and remain stuck there...

Anyway I have boiled it all down to a simple example.

https://github.com/trapper-/autolayout-glitch

- Test with iPhone and if using simulator then enable the software keyboard.
- You will see many visual glitches just playing around scrolling, selecting fields and rotating.
- For a simple repeatable example.
- Scroll down to the bottom.
- Select one of the last couple of `UITextField's`, so that the `UITableView` will need to scroll to ensure the field will be visible.
- Rotate the device.

Comment: Although not ideal, but a reloadData call on tableView instance should help.  Did you try it?

Comment: Autolayout does not work well with UITableView.  Consider using a CollectionView.  This is a great post about the limits of UITableView: https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2017/the-case-for-deprecating-uitableview/

Comment: Are you saying `UICollectionView` doesn't have these same kinds of glitches? If so that would be a great solution.

Answer (score 1):

I toyed with your code for a few minutes, because I struggled through similar issues. I was hopeful I could help, but I didn't get it fully fixed.

What I can offer is that I did make *some* progress.

When the device rotates, you should implement the UIViewcontroller methods that tell you it will happen, and did happen. When it will happen, cache off the visible rows. Then after it did, reload the table and scroll to those visible rows.

It looks like this:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    // Save the visible row position
    self.visibleRows = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
}

-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    // Scroll to the saved position prior to screen rotate
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[self.visibleRows objectAtIndex:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO];
}
```

visibleRows is an array @property on your ViewController.

This made it go to the rightish place ( I suspect that if you actually stored off the individual cell that the user was manipulating, this would get you 100% to the right cell every time.

What this did not do, is that there were still the dancing UITextFields being laid out incorrectly (on occasion) with several device rotations.

Again, not a solution - but I wanted to share what I saw so hopefully this helps you find the solution.

Good Luck!

Comment: Not a bad idea regarding the visible row tracking, but I also have a lot of problems with the scrollToRowAtIndexPath method. It doesn't know where to scroll to. ie doesn't correctly translate an indexPath to the right contentOffset.

Comment: Yeah, I suspect that has to do with the fact that the cells are getting laid out all squirrely in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain your issue is with the line:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44;
```

This results in the tableview doing some optimisation around this estimated height. I couldn't quite figure out why this breaks when the textfield is selected, but that's what I managed to narrow it down to. If you do actually calculate the height for each row explicitly, the issue seems to go away (note that this is just a rough example, and you would need to put a little more thought into the actual implementation):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row % 2) {

        return 44.f;

    } else {

        NSString *text = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";

        CGRect frame = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(350.f, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                          options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                       attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.f] }
                                          context:nil];

        return frame.size.height;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at that project.  My best suggestion to mitigate some of the issues was to improve your estimated height calculation.  If the text view cells are going to be larger then the estimated height needs to be closer to the average height of the cell, so on rotation there is less wild resizing.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath (NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if (indexPath.row % 2) {
        return 44.0f;
    } else {
        return 175.0f;
    }
}
```

Now as for the weird issue with the UITextField,  I think you may need to consider that these cells are being reused even on rotation, so if the UITextField is still first responder even though the cell has been reused, then this is where the keyboard is having trouble tracking the text field.

You can see this result by just setting a tag on the cell and watch how it randomly changes order on rotation like so:

```
NSString* cellID = @"TextFieldCell";
TextFieldCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
NSLog(@"cell %@, changing to %@", @(cell.tag), @(indexPath.row));
cell.tag = indexPath.row;
return cell;
```

My suggestion for that is to either 1) not use text fields in table view cells, or 2) think of a new way to let the user input text on scrolling items. For example, put a text field copy in the view on top of the table view and manage that manually while inputting text and then copy the text back to the cell when text is done.
3) option 3 is to try to see if a keyboard manager library might help.  I really like using [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager).  It is really handy for solving keyboard management.